# Powerpoint Modify Chart Legend width

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop, powerpoint

I am using VB.net to create charts in Powerpoint and have a small problem: The customer wants the legend bigger than the original design. Is this possible with Interop?

I have a basically this structure:

```
Dim TargetChartas Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Chart
TargetChart.HasLegend=true

With TargetChart.Legend
                .Position = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionTop
                .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue
                .Format.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue
End Width
```

But I am unable to find a width property - like any normal shape posess.

Do you have any Idea how to do this?

I added the excel tag because the charts are basically excel charts.

Argh: I need more tea. I just realized that Office 2010 HAS a width property, whereas 2007 does not. So I just have to check the powerpoint version... oh joy...

Comment: Has this stopped being a question? You can add your own answer if it has.

Comment: +1 to @Remou - submit your own answer as soon as trouble is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Powerpoint 2010 and later has a width property, so it works there. The width and left properties are somewhat weird, they seem to be relative to the chart. So expect some experimentation.

If you have to support Office 2007 you can check the application version: Chart.application.version 14.0 is Office 2010. I converted it to a number and check if it is greater than 14.